# Issues in Expandble list view child items

Tags: android, expandablelistview

For example suppose Foodmenu is parent item in that burger,piza are list submenu and one more parent item Shop menu in that veg shop,non veg shop are list submneu.Now when i click on Foodmenu it shows correct data .next i click on Shopmenu it shows shop menu data but in Foodmenu daata is changed it shows shop menu data how can i solve this?

```
private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> Mainmenu;
private ArrayList child;
private ArrayList<Object> Submenu;
String[] sub;

@Override

public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if(view == null){

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, parent, false);

    }

    TextView childItem = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.child_layout);
    String item=Submenu.get(groupPosition).toString().replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("\"", "");
        Log.e("Submenu",""+Submenu.get(0).toString());
    sub=item.split(",");
    Log.e("sub",""+sub);

        for (int k = 0; k < sub.length; k++) {
            child.add(sub[k]);
            childItem.setText(child.get(childPosition).toString());

        }


    return view;

}
```

Comment: Where do you set the values in `Submenu`?

Comment: that values are coming from server means json values

Comment: Loose guess: Have you tried using `childPosition` in place of `groupPosition` where you set the value for `String item`? It would help me understand your problem if you shared screenshots of your UI.